# JPA serial numbers using a customer ID generation

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

I get this error when I try to generate serial numbers for ID using a random generator instead of the built-in strategies:

```
run:
[EL Info]: 2015-03-27 18:22:05.047--ServerSession(1185812646)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
[EL Info]: connection: 2015-03-27 18:22:09.295--ServerSession(1185812646)--file:/C:/Users/Sobhie/Desktop/people/build/classes/_peoplePU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2015-03-27 18:22:09.498--ServerSession(1185812646)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'R' used in key specification without a key length
Error Code: 1170
Call: CREATE TABLE PERSON (R LONGBLOB NOT NULL, FNAME VARCHAR(255), ID BIGINT, LNAME VARCHAR(255), X INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (R))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE PERSON (R LONGBLOB NOT NULL, FNAME VARCHAR(255), ID BIGINT, LNAME VARCHAR(255), X INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (R))")
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking, do you have a code sample to include?

Comment: Looks like your SQL is missing a length in the `PRIMARY KEY(R)` part of the command. I'm not up to date on my MySQL syntax or I'd post an Answer, sorry. But if you look up the PRIMARY KEY syntax I bet you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You current custom primary key strategy result in primary keys mapped as blobs (so probably a serialized object)).
Out of the box, BLOB or TEXT cannot be used as PRIMARY KEY in mysql as

a) mysql has limit on how many characeters can form part of the index (so whole TEXT content is out of the question), 
b) there is no size constraint for TEXT (for example TEXT(512))

To use TEXT as Primary Key, the index length must be declared explicit (so mysql will look only at the first X characters).

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (R TEXT NOT NULL, FNAME VARCHAR(255), ..., KEY ix_length_r (R(255)))
```

If your R values are not unique in the first XX characters it will not work.

But the mysql ix limit lenght, comes down to 255 for unicodecharacters and to 765 for latin-1. So for unicode you are basically as good as using VARCHAR(255) as your primary key.

You mentioned random number generator for your primary keys but they are mapped as blobs. I don't believe having keys longer than 255 chars makes any sense (it is a huge space about 2E462, so more than atoms in the universe!!!), so you should limit yourself to having them as simple varchar.

But most likely you wanted to use simple Long, but you messed up with your mappings. Impossible to say without the code though.